# 二次元配列のリスト内のソート結果が上手く表示されない

Tags: python, python3

お疲れ様です。python初心者のものです。
二次元配列内でソートを行いたく、プログラムを作成したのですが。
コンパイルした結果が、

```
[<__main__.gate object at 0x7f89dbc994e0>, <__main__.gate object at 0x7f89dbc99518>, <__main__.gate object at 0x7f89dbc99550>, <__main__.gate object at 0x7f89dbc99588>, <__main__.gate object at 0x7f89dbc995c0>, <__main__.gate object at 0x7f89dbc995f8>, <__main__.gate object at 0x7f89dbc99630>]
```

となり、値が表示されません。

結果としては、

```
Gate=(gate(0,2),gate(2,4),gate(0,4),gate(0,2),gate(0,4),gate(0,3),gate(0,2))
```

と小さい値が左となるようにGateを直したいのですが、コンパイル結果がなぜこうなるかわかりません。
助力していただけると幸いです。

```
class gate():
    def __init__(self,target,control):
        self.tar = target
        self.con = control

Gate = (gate(2,0), gate(2,4), gate(4,0), gate(0,2), gate(4,0), gate(3,0), gate(0,2))

def sort(Gate):
    gate_sort = []
    for g in Gate:
        if g.tar > g.con:
            gate_sort.append(gate(g.con, g.tar))
        elif g.tar < g.con:
            gate_sort.append(gate(g.tar, g.con))
    return gate_sort

print(sort(Gate))
```

Comment: `return gate_sort`の部分のインデントはこれでお手元のプログラム通りですか？

Comment: 内部の値を表示したい場合は `gate` クラスに `__repr__` メソッドを追加するとよろしいかと思います。

Comment: return gate_sortのインテンドが間違っていましたので修正しました。

Comment: @sato さん、対応ありがとうございます。ちなみにこのインデントで実行したときに質問文にあるような出力になるということで合っていますか？

Comment: 出力結果は[<__main__.gate object at 0x7f89dbc994e0>, <__main__.gate object at 0x7f89dbc99518>, <__main__.gate object at 0x7f89dbc99550>, <__main__.gate object at 0x7f89dbc99588>, <__main__.gate object at 0x7f89dbc995c0>, <__main__.gate object at 0x7f89dbc995f8>, <__main__.gate object at 0x7f89dbc99630>]となりました。こちらも質問文の修正をしておきます。

Comment: @metropolisさん、出力結果が無事表示されました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @sato さん、ご自身で解決できた場合は質問文に追記するのではなく[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)の形にして頂けるとありがたいです。（もしかしたらまだ時間制限の問題で自己回答できないかもしれませんが、少しお待ちいただければできるようになります）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

参考までに、Python 3.6 において `f-strings`([PEP 498: Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/))という仕組みが導入されました。

format メソッドを使用する場合は以下の様に記述するかと思いますが、

```
def __repr__(self):
  return 'gate({}, {})'.format(self.tar, self.con)
```

f-strings ではブレース対の中に変数名を書くことができる様になりました。

```
def __repr__(self):
  return f'gate({self.tar}, {self.con})'

## print(Gate) を実行
Gate = (gate(2,0), gate(2,4), gate(4,0), gate(0,2), gate(4,0), gate(3,0), gate(0,2))
print(Gate)
=>
(gate(2, 0), gate(2, 4), gate(4, 0), gate(0, 2), gate(4, 0), gate(3, 0), gate(0, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

`sort` 関数自体は実行されていますが、その実行結果の値が人間に読みやすい形で出力されていないだけです。`gate` クラスを良い感じに `print` するため、`__str__` メソッドもしくは `__repr__` メソッドを実装する必要があります。

Python の [`print`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html#print) は、各オブジェクトを `str` した結果の文字列を出力しようとします。自分で作ったクラスのインスタンスに対して `str` が適用された場合、`str` はまずそのクラスに `__str__` メソッドが無いか探します。あればそれを使い、無ければ `__repr__` メソッドが無いか探します。よって、これらを実装する必要があります。

たとえば：

```
class MyClass:
    def __repr__(self):
        return "MyClass()"
    def __str__(self):
        return "MyClass()"

x = MyClass()
print(x)  # MyClass() と出力されます。
```

このことは [`str` のドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html#str)などに書かれています。

> *encoding* も *errors* も与えられない場合、 `str(object)` は `object.__str__()` の結果を返します。これは "略式の" つまり読み易い *object* の文字列表現です。文字列オブジェクトに対してはその文字列自体を返します。 *object* が `__str__()` メソッドを持たない場合、`str()` は代わりに `repr(object)` の結果を返します。

---

その他細かい点：

- Python のよくある流儀的には、クラスの名前を `Gate` にして変数の名前を `gate` にする方が自然です。参考：[PEP-8](https://pep8-ja.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/#id31)
- 質問の最初の版で `[<__main__.gate object at 0x7f5710078518>]` と出力されていたのは、`return gate_sort` のインデントがおかしく、`sort` 関数の返すリストの長さが必ず 1 以下になるバグがあったためです。つまりこれは「`gate` クラスのインスタンスをひとつ要素に持つ、長さ 1 のリスト」が返ってきています。
- 「コンパイル」と「プログラムの実行」を区別してください。おそらく質問者さんが行った動作はコンパイルでは無いです。

Comment: コンパイルの意味を勘違いしてました、、、。丁寧に書いて頂き、とても感謝しております。